# Passing client-side date using server actions in Next.js 14

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js, server-action

In a sample nextjs app, I have a form where I can submit usernames to the server using server actions. Along side with username, I want to be able to send the timestamp of the form submission. For this I created a controlled hidden input to save the date.

Here is what I tried:

```
export default function Form() {

    const [date, setDate] = useState("");

    const [_, action] = useFormState(addUser, {});

    const handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        setDate(new Date().toLocaleString());
        e.currentTarget.form.requestSubmit();
    }

    return (
        <form action={action}>
            <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="username" />
            <input type="hidden" name="date" value={date} />
            <button onClick={handleSubmit}>Add</button>
        </form>
    );
}
```

The problem is the form will be submitted before the component gets re-rendered, so value of the date input is an empty string

Comment: I did not provide you with a complete solution, but the information you need to resolve your issue. Try to stay as close as possible with the official docs.

Answer (score 0):

See [this part of Learn Next tutorial](https://nextjs.org/learn/dashboard-app/mutating-data#4-pass-the-id-to-the-server-action) and [Server Actions and Mutations](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/data-fetching/server-actions-and-mutations)

I'm not sure, if you can intercept form submission the way you do. See [Programmatic form submission](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/data-fetching/server-actions-and-mutations). And use [bind instead of hidden fields](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/data-fetching/server-actions-and-mutations#passing-additional-arguments).

I would also think about taking the timestamp in the action and not in the form submission itself. The action seams to be the natural place for me.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it can be done using the `bind` method, but i want the date to be included in the FormData object. Additionally, in some use cases, the timestamp **must** be taken on the client side, as the client time and the server time may differ.

Comment: Client time is not secure and can be manipulated. Correct Server time is under your control. Please elaborate why one would prefer a client time stamp? The bind method includes the data in `FormData`! As I told you. The well documented way includes Server Actions, React `<form`>, Programmatic form submission and `bind`, if you really need the “client timestamp”.